Google sign-in not working for flutter web app after moving to a subdomain
We have a flutter web app that uses Google sign-in and it worked perfectly on our root domain but after moving to a subdomain it doesn't work anymore.
This is the error that shows in the web browser when attempting to use Google sign-in:

Error 400: redirect_uri_mismatch
You can't sign in to this app because it doesn't comply with Google's OAuth 2.0 policy.
If you're the app developer, register the JavaScript origin in the Google Cloud Console.
Request details: origin=https://web.mydomain.com flowName=GeneralOAuthFlow

(I replaced our domain name with "mydomain.com" in the error message above.)
We did indeed try adding https://web.mydomain.com to the allowed javascript origins in the Google Cloud Console, but that did not solve the problem.
I don't know what to do with the "flowName=GeneralOAuthFlow" part of the error message (I assume nothing but please tell me if there's some action to take on that).

This question is similar to: Google OAuth 2 Error 400: redirect_uri_mismatch but redirect uri is compliant and already registered in Google Cloud Console. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
